# MAXIFS function that increments to return 2nd,3rd largest numbers

Tags: excel, list, function, excel-formula

I have a column called Paid which consists of currency figures which is in column A.
I also have a column called ID to uniquely define each of the rows which is in column B.
I am trying to make a top ten list of the highest results from this column.

For the first result, I use a simple MAX function.
For the following, I use

```
=MAXIFS(Combined!$A$1:$A$2916,$A$1:$A$2916,"<"&$C1)
```

where C1 is the first result in the top 10 list.

THE ISSUE: Currently, if two results are equal in Paid, one will get skipped and not be on the list.

I've tried using something in the nature of

```
=MAXIFS($A$1:$A$2916,$B$2:$B$2916,"<>"&$D1)
```

where D1 is the ID of the 1st in the top 10 list.

My issue here is that I want to use a condition to say that none of the ID's in the B column appear in the above entries in the D column(IDs of the top 10) and I don't know how to do this without brute forcing and writing each cell into each condition.

Is there a smoother way to write a "not in" check in a maxif function?
Thanks

For reference, an example of what I want would look like:

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fahgs.png)

Comment: Why not use large().

Comment: Do you have sample data and expected results to go with this?

Comment: @SolarMike Ah, that could help as it returns multiple values if the value of paid is the same. Let me look into it.

Comment: Then have a look on here for "Top 5" or "Top 10" - have a solution that may help uses aggregate()

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=INDEX(SORT(A2:B11,1,-1),SEQUENCE(10),{1,2})
```

Where `10` is your top N figure.

---

**Note:** The above works fine in retrieving only 10 figures, yet if you insist you want top have ID '5' above '3' in rank 2, and ID '9' above '1' for rank 8, then use:

```
=INDEX(SORTBY(A2:B11,A2:A11,-1;B2:B11,-1),SEQUENCE(10),{1,2})
```

I could see this being relevant if you have two identical payments "battle" for e.g. 1st or 10th place with one of multiple id's comming short.

[image]